# Accessing EJBs from pojo class==>org.jboss.remote-naming

Tags: ejb, wildfly, ejb-3.0

I have deployed Test.jar over wildfly server at path - wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments.
Test.jar contains java file Test.java.  'main' method is present in Test.java file.  Test.java file is accessing a EJB class named as 'TestBean.java'. 
MANIFEST.MF(in META-INF directory) is present in Test.jar.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_66 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: Test
```

'jboss-deployment-structure.xml' is also present in META-INF directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
<deployment>
    <dependencies>              
        <module name="org.jboss.remote-naming" export="true" />        
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
```

but i am still getting error while accessing Test.java class.

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory]
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:674)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
at getSessionInterfaceObject(Test.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:72)
at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:61)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:672)
... 8 more
```

i am accessing Test.java using command 'java -jar Test.jar'.

Test.java contains following code for creation of context object.

```
public static Object  getSessionInterfaceObject(String ipAddress, String jndiLookupName) throws NamingException{        
    Object interfaceObject = null;
    Context ejbRootNamingContext = null;
    Context context = null;
    try
      {
        String EJBUSER = "EjbUser";
        String EJBPASS = "ejbuser123";
        String PORT = "8080";
Hashtable jndiProps = new Hashtable();
        jndiProps.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        jndiProps.put("java.naming.provider.url", "http-remoting://" + ipAddress + ":" + PORT);
        jndiProps.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", Boolean.valueOf(false));
        jndiProps.put("org.jboss.ejb.client.scoped.context", Boolean.valueOf(true));
        jndiProps.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        jndiProps.put("endpoint.name", "client-endpoint");
        jndiProps.put("remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED", Boolean.valueOf(false));
        jndiProps.put("remote.connections", "default");
        jndiProps.put("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS", Boolean.valueOf(false));
        jndiProps.put("remote.connection.default.host", ipAddress);
        jndiProps.put("remote.connection.default.port", PORT);
        jndiProps.put("remote.connection.default.username", EJBUSER);
        jndiProps.put("remote.connection.default.password", EJBPASS);
        context = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
        ejbRootNamingContext = (Context)context.lookup("ejb:");
        interfaceObject = ejbRootNamingContext.lookup(jndiLookupName);
      }           
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          ex.printStackTrace();
      }
return interfaceObject;
}
```

Could someone help me understand why am I getting that error?

Comment: You are trying to do remote rather than local calls from inside the container. This is way more complex than it needs to be, just go direct to the initial context lookup without any remote stuff

Comment: Initially i tried local calls inside the container, but got following error - --  javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial

Comment: @Will T Please reply!!!

Comment: When working locally you typically use injection rather than manual JNDI calls. Provided the calling code is a bean, just use @EJB annotation